# Can I build a level 1 character with an uncommon weapon if they have access to it?

Tags: magic-items, character-creation, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

I'm looking to join a local Pathfinder Society game, and I'd like to rebuild a character from a failed AP. They are a gymnast swashbuckler that uses a bladed scarf as their primary weapon.

What I'm running into is that I was told that I can only use common options to build the character at level 1, and the scarf is uncommon. It seems cut and dry, but the section of the rules regarding access confuses me. The example it gives is that a gnome would have access to a gnomish hook hammer, but it doesn't say if the character could have said weapon at level 1.

To fully clarify my question, if I choose the Saga Lands as my region of origin, which according to AONPRD gives me access to a bladed scarf, can I have that weapon at level 1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Yes, an uncommon, standard weapon just requires access.

The [bladed scarf](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=273) includes the following:

> ***PFS Note*** For the purposes of Pathfinder Society play, choosing the following region as a Home Region (or with the World Traveler boon) grants access [to] this item: Saga Lands

AoNPRD includes [a page on PFS play](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx), which has the following image:
[image: Legality of rarities in PFS]

and shows the icons for, respectively, standard, limited, and restricted options (this applies to gear, spells, etc.):
[image: Standard option icon] [image: Limited option icon] [image: Restricted option icon]

An example of a limited piece of gear is a [spellstriker staff](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2258): the limited icon is in the top-left of the block. Bladed scarf has a standard icon.

As the bladed scarf is (1) uncommon and (2) standard, you must have either (a) selected an option that grants access or (b) gained access to it through a boon. As you've chosen Saga Lands as your home region, you satisfy (a) and are able to select it as a starting item.

Answer (score 7):

## You can use Bladed Scarf on level 1

The description of Access never mentions level:

> Uncommon elements sometimes have an Access entry in their stat block. A character who meets the specifications listed there has access to that option just like they would to a common option, even though it’s uncommon. These entries include a statement such as “follower of Shelyn,” “member of the Pathfinder Society,” or “from Absalom.”

PFS has another classification independently of this. Some uncommon items might be freely available in Society play, and some common items might be unavailable.
Check Shivers' answer above.